# Python random sampling data considering class (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to do random sampling on Pandas Dataframe.

For instance, the input data is like below, and I want to do 50% sampling, considering the column CLASS which has binary values.

```
A1 A2 CLASS
1  1    X
1  2    X
2  1    Y
2  2    Y
2  3    Y
2  4    Y
```

As a result, I want to get 2 data frames, which contain the 50% of Xs and 50% of Ys.

```
A1 A2 CLASS
1  1    X
2  2    Y
2  4    Y

A1 A2 CLASS
1  2    X
2  1    Y
2  3    Y
```

Is there any simple way for this kind of sampling?

Comment: It is not very clear what you want. does the CLASS column have 50% X also in the input data? Because in that case, what you want is trivial.

Comment: You can use [Stratified k-fold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#stratified-k-fold) for this

Comment: @Konstantin That's right. As there are 2 Xs and 4 Ys, I want to divide them into 2 tables that have 1 X and 2 Ys(50% of classes), respectively.

Comment: @EdChum Stratified k-fold seems to be one kind of solution. I would try it if pandas or numpy do not support those kind of sampling. Thank you.

Comment: You can do this and it's trivial but I don't see the point of reinventing the wheel

Comment: why not adopting EdChum solution? if you use Anaconda, sklearn is 'base' library ...

Comment: Thank you for advice. I will try to use sklearn library or installing anaconda.

Comment: Can't you slice by class and then do a normal pandas [DataFrame.sample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html)? Then you could [Index.diff](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) find the other "remaining" sample.

Comment: @caiohamamura I solved it by using k-fold, but that seems to be a good idea. Thanks.

Comment: Now pandas seems to offer the libary 'train_test_split' which can do this kind of work very easily.